# Subtracting next date to create end date in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with [Date] in column E. I need to create an [End Date] column in F. I want it to just subtract 1 day from next rows date per landowner. Only caveat is when [Status] = "Signed" we just take the value from [Date], not -1 from that date. If [Status] <> "Signed" then just fill in today's date:

Formula I tried:

```
=IF(A2<>A1, E3-1, IFERROR(IF(F2=FALSE, TODAY(), ""), ""))
```

Error message in column F and expected output in column G:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this single `array-style` formula in ***Cell_F2***:*

```js
=map(A2:A,C2:C,E2:E,lambda(Σ,Δ,Λ,if(or(Σ="",Λ=""),,let(x,chooserows(filter(E2:E,A2:A=Σ),countif(A2:Σ,Σ)+1),
    ifs(Λ="Signed",Λ,iserror(x),today(),1,x-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Just getting a #REF error

Comment: Add the formula in **Only** Cell_F2 (*don't drag the formula down*) and make sure to **clear the range F3:F** of any existing formulas or data so that the arrayformula in F2 can expand freely downwards...